# Rotate nine patch image

Tags: android, nine-patch

I have a nine patch images already created in my proect, which corresponds for background to chat message : left and right sides.

[image]

[image]

As you can see size right image is bigger than left one. So i had to either change size of lef image to be like right in size, or rotate right to 180 degrees for it to be left.

I did the rotation using ***Photoshop*** but it causes an error at compilation :

> :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'. Some file crunching failed, see logs for details

Also I used a java library to [resize nine patch image](https://github.com/redwarp/9-Patch-Resizer/releases), but it's not working in the way that I need, I had to resize an image with actual numbers for size.

My question : if somebody know how to properly rotate this kind of image in photoshop or some app to resize this kind of images please help me.

***PS: I don't have source images so I can't recreate nine patch from a scratch***

Answer (score 1):

you make it by photoshop and save as another name. then delete bad image and rename new file again. after that do 9patch again and delete non-9patch image.

Comment: I didn't get what you mean, what to make by photoshop, what bad image to delete, on what image do 9patch?

Comment: @NikMyers bad image means small image that you don't want it. when you save image by photoshop your 9patch is destroyed, use 9patch tools to do it again. I hope this is clear.

Comment: providing example would save other's time. I would recommend that you give a clear example